# Unexpected Output of the program

Tags: c++, algorithm, breadth-first-search

problem statement : http://www.spoj.com/problems/NAKANJ/
MY SOLUTION:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int x[10]={0,2,2,-2,-2,1,1,-1,-1};
int y[10]={0,1,-1,1,-1,2,-2,2,-2};
int bfs(int a1,int b1,int a2,int b2)
{
    pair<int,int> p;
    int i;
    queue<pair<int,int> >q;
    int moves[9][9],visit[9][9],m,n;
    memset(moves,0,sizeof(moves));
    memset(visit,0,sizeof(visit));
    p.first=a1;
    p.second=b1;
    q.push(p);
    moves[a1][b1]=0;
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        p=q.front();
        q.pop();
        if(p.first==a2&&p.second==b2)
            return moves[a2][b2];
        for(i=1;i<=8;i++)
        {
            m=p.first+x[i];
            n=p.second+y[i];
            if(m>8||m<1||n>8||n<1)
                continue;
            else
            {
                visit[m][n]=1;
                moves[m][n]=moves[p.first][p.second]+1;
                q.push(make_pair(m,n));
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    long long int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string d,f;
        cin>>d>>f;
        int s=d[0]-'a';int r=f[0]-'a';
        cout<<bfs(s+1,(int)d[1],r+1,(int)f[1])<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Input :
3
a1 h8
a1 c2
h8 c3

output :
-1217403904
-1217403904 
-1217403904
```

what is the reason of this weird output. logic and algorithm implementation seem fine to me . any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `moves` array has 9 rows and 9 columns -

```
int moves[9][9];
```

While you return something from moves like this -

```
if(p.first==a2&&p.second==b2)
   return moves[a2][b2];
```

Make a check whether a2 and b2 are less than 9 -

```
if(p.first==a2&&p.second==b2){
   if(a2 < 9 && b2 <9){
    return moves[a2][b2];
  }
}
```

Comment: That didnt change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your `bfs()` function reaches the end while not returning anything, and it's expected to return `int`.

That means that you are either ignoring compiler warnings or silencing them, in both cases it's a bad idea, turn warnings on and listen to them, they tell you that your code almost surely has bugs.

Also, don't do this

```
int s=d[0]-'a';int r=f[0]-'a';
```

it's too low quality code that makes your program alsmot impossible to understand, do it like this

```
int s;
int r;

s = d[0] - 'a';
r = f[0] - 'a';
```

Comment: It does return `return moves[a2][b2];`, but may be that line is not reached, idk

Comment: i did return an integer in my bfs function. and that line would eventually be reached i guess.

Comment: @SarvagyaAgarwal don't guess test, and always use a fallback value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is likely the problem :

When you are casting a character which is not a digit, you should do :

```
int char_not_digit = char - 'a' ;
```

and when a digit to an int,

```
int char_digit = char - '0';
```

Look at the solution [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d3611e537a46e63)

Thus all 0th position character in the input string should be casted to `int` with subtracting `'a'` and all 1th position character in the input string should be casted to `int` by subtracting `'0'`.